# An error happens while following pytorch tutorial

Tags: python, pytorch

I was following pytorch tutorial, training a classifier using CIFAR10 dataset. All I've done was copy and paste codes in tutorial page to Pycharm project, yet I faced unknown errors. And I also used Jupyter notebook to run same code, and met errors again. Below is the code and errors. What should I do?

```
import torch
import torchvision
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.models as models
import torch.autograd as Variable
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim

transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                    download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                      shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                   download=True, transform=transform)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                     shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

classes = ('plane', 'car', 'bird', 'cat',
       'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck')


class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
    x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)
    return x


net = Net()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

for epoch in range(2):

  running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):

      inputs, labels = data

      optimizer.zero_grad()

      outputs = net(inputs)
      loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
      loss.backward()
      optimizer.step()

      running_loss += loss.item()
      if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 mini-batches
        print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
              (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
        running_loss = 0.0

print('Finished Training')
```

Error in Pycharm:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
exitcode = _main(fd)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
prepare(preparation_data)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare
_fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
run_name="__mp_main__")
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "D:\Users\VML1\PycharmProjects\untitled1\HY1.py", line 57, in <module>
for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 417, in __iter__
return DataLoaderIter(self)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 234, in __init__
w.start()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
self._popen = self._Popen(self)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
return Popen(process_obj)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 33, in __init__
prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 143, in get_preparation_data
_check_not_importing_main()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 136, in _check_not_importing_main
is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError: 
    An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
    current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Users/VML1/PycharmProjects/untitled1/HY1.py", line 57, in <module>
for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 417, in __iter__
return DataLoaderIter(self)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 234, in __init__
w.start()
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
self._popen = self._Popen(self)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 223, in _Popen
return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
return Popen(process_obj)
File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__
reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\pytorch\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Error in Jupyter:

```
TypeError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1dd1ecde814e> in <module>
---> 45         outputs = net(inputs)
     46         loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     47         loss.backward()

c:\users\vml1\anaconda3\envs\hypytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    355             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    356         else:
--> 357             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    358         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    359             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

c:\users\vml1\anaconda3\envs\hypytorch\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\resnet.py in forward(self, x)
    137 
    138     def forward(self, x):
--> 139         x = self.conv1(x)
    140         x = self.bn1(x)
    141         x = self.relu(x)

c:\users\vml1\anaconda3\envs\hypytorch\lib\site-                
packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    355             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    356         else:
--> 357             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    358         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    359             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

    c:\users\vml1\anaconda3\envs\hypytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py in forward(self, input)
    280     def forward(self, input):
    281         return F.conv2d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 282                         self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    283 
    284 

c:\users\vml1\anaconda3\envs\hypytorch\lib\site-    
packages\torch\nn\functional.py in conv2d(input, weight, bias, stride,     
padding, dilation, groups)
     88                 _pair(0), groups, torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark,
     89                 torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic,     
torch.backends.cudnn.enabled)
---> 90     return f(input, weight, bias)
     91 
     92 

TypeError: argument 0 is not a Variable
```

Comment: I have no problem running the above code. Here's the list of module and version I am using, try updating the module if they are not same it might help.                                   
   `Python:3.6.5,numpy:1.15.3,torch:0.4.1,torchvision:0.2.1`

Comment: @Biranjan, I updated numpy and torch, torchvision. For what reason, no error was caused in Anaconda Prompt and Jupyter notebook(still doesn't work in Pycharm-I have no reason why). Thanks a lot!